# Merge column into one string from 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I want to merge one column into one string from 2D list.
Are there better ways to merge it?

```
lists = [['H', 'W'], ['e', 'o'], ['l', 'r'], ['l', 'l'], ['o','d']]
str1 = ''
str2 = ''
for i in lists:
    str1 += i[0]
    str2 += i[1]
print(str1, str2) #('Hello', 'World')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `zip` and `str.join` in a loop:

```py
out = [''.join(tpl) for tpl in zip(*lists)]
print(*out)
```

Output:

```py
Hello World
```